# How to print the least frequent number in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm doing a programme that has to print the most and the least frequent number of an array, the part that finds the most frequent works fine but I'm stuck in the one to find the least.

This is the code I have for the most frequent(this works the way it should):

```
//Most frequent term
for (i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
    {
        count = 1;
        for (j = i; j < n_elements; j++)
        {
            if (v[i] == v[j])
            {
                count++;
                if (count > count_max)
                {
                    mfn = v[j];
                    count_max = count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the one that doesn't work is this:

```
//Least frequent term
for (i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        min_num = v[0];
        for (j = i; j < 14; j++)
        {
            if (min_num == v[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count < count_min)
        {
            count_min = count;
            min_num = v[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `std::map` to count and then in single pass over that map you can find both.

Comment: Apart from that this looks a lot more complicated than it has to be: In the top loop you are using `n_elements` and in the bottom you've hardcoded `14`. That doesn't look right.

Comment: How is the array `v` defined? Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 3):

Associative array aka [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) are commonly used for calculating number of occurrences. Even example on cppreference.com for `std::map::operator[]` shows such [program](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

So first use it to calculate how many times each number appears in your array:

```
std::map<int,int> counts;
for( int i : v ) counts[i]++;
```

done! Now we can use single pass to find both most and less frequent elements. You can even use standard algorithm [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element):

```
auto pair = std::minmax_element( counts.begin(), counts.end(), 
    []( const auto &p1, const auto &p2 ) { return p1.second < p2.second; } );
```

we are done, just print results:

```
std::cout << "Less frequent is:" << pair.first->first << std::endl;
std::cout << "Most frequent is:" << pair.second->first << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is incomplete but I assume the top part of your code looks something like this:

```
int* v = new int[14] { 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 };
int n_elements = 14

int count;
int count_max = 0;
int mfn = -1;
int min_num = -1;
int count_min = INT_MAX;
int i, j;
```

**First things first: Style & Improvements**

1. Declare your variables just when you need them, not at the start of the code. This helps with clarity.
2. You have one variable *min_num* for least frequent number and one *mfn* for most frequent number. Stay consistent! *mfn* could be called *max_num*.
3. In your least frequent loop you have the *count* check outside the *j* loop. This is saving performance compared to having it inside. Do it in your most frequent loop as well!
4. In your most frequent loop you used *n_elements* as the loop limits, in your least frequent term you hardcoded 14. Use *n_elements* here as well, otherwise it will get annoying when you change *v*'s number of elements!

Your code should look similar to this now:

```
int* v = new int[14] { 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 };
int n_elements = 14

// Most frequent term
int count_max = INT_MIN; // lowest number possible initially, so other counts will be above
int max_num = -1; // default value
for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = i; j < n_elements; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] == v[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > count_max)
    {
        max_num = v[i];
        count_max = count;
    }
}

// Least frequent term
int count_min = INT_MAX; // largest number possible initially, so other counts will be below
int min_num = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    min_num = v[0];
    for (int j = i; j < n_elements; j++)
    {
        if (min_num == v[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count < count_min)
    {
        count_min = count;
        min_num = v[i];
    }
}
```

**The problems:**

1. In your least frequent term, inside your i-loop you set *min_num = v[0]*. This always overwrites your previous result. Do it just as you did in your most frequent term instead.
2. You start the j-loop from *i* on. This means that numbers that come before *i* are skipped when counting. Imagine your array is { 5, 5, 7 } and you want to find the least frequent number. So your algorithm starts counting:

| i | current number | numbers checked in j-loop | resulting count | min_num | count_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| initially | - | - | - | -1 | INT_MAX |
| 0 | 5 | 5, 5, 7 | 2 | → 5 (update 2 < INT_MAX) | → 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 5, 7 | 1 | → 5 (update 1 < 2) | → 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 7 | 1 | 5 (no update 1 equals 1) | 1 |

So the last occurence of a number will always be the result. Start counting *j* from 0 on instead.
Now your code should look something like this and give the correct result:

```
int* v = new int[14] { 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 };
int n_elements = 14

// Most frequent term
int count_max = INT_MIN; // lowest number possible initially, so other counts will be above
int max_num = -1; // default value
for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n_elements; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] == v[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > count_max)
    {
        max_num = v[i];
        count_max = count;
    }
}

// Least frequent term
int count_min = INT_MAX; // largest number possible initially, so other counts will be below
int min_num = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n_elements; j++)
    {
        if (v[i] == v[j])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count < count_min)
    {
        count_min = count;
        min_num = v[i];
    }
}
```

Last notes: Using an std::map as [Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582840/4458006) suggests would be more efficient for big arrays.